# Timestamps should be rounded to every two days - aggregate error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are testing this with a Snowflake Trial account by aggregating some of the sample data on a the date column on different time intervals. We used the documentation for reference.

```sql
USE DATABASE SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA;
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;

SELECT 
   O_ORDERDATE,
   TIME_SLICE(O_ORDERDATE, 2, 'Day', 'START') AS "START OF SLICE",
   TIME_SLICE(O_ORDERDATE, 2, 'Day', 'END') AS "END OF SLICE",
   count(*) as "every 2 day total"
FROM TPCH_SF001.ORDERS
GROUP BY "START OF SLICE","END OF SLICE";
```

We are running into this error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 7 'ORDERS.O_ORDERDATE' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.

Where can we use Time_slice() to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is actually in the error message.  I believe this is what the user is looking for:

USE DATABASE SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA;
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;

```
SELECT 
   TIME_SLICE(O_ORDERDATE, 2, 'Day', 'START') AS "START OF SLICE",
   TIME_SLICE(O_ORDERDATE, 2, 'Day', 'END') AS "END OF SLICE",
   count(*) as "every 2 day total"
FROM TPCH_SF001.ORDERS
GROUP BY "START OF SLICE","END OF SLICE";
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue is simply that all non-aggregated columns need to be in the group by clause.  I find that using the ordinal position is easier when working w/ computed columns.

```
SELECT 
   O_ORDERDATE,
   TIME_SLICE(O_ORDERDATE, 2, 'Day', 'START') AS "START OF SLICE",
   TIME_SLICE(O_ORDERDATE, 2, 'Day', 'END') AS "END OF SLICE",
   count(*) as "every 2 day total"
FROM TPCH_SF100.ORDERS
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```